# Efficiency in Groovy Method

Tags: java, performance, methods, groovy

I would like to know which is the most efficient way of doing the following calculations in one method. Imagine we have different types of vehicles (2 or 4 wheels and depending the vehicle type I will use the same method.

The 2 global variable are the following:

```
def total2Wheels = 0.00
def total4Wheels = 0.00
```

Depending on the vehicle type I will call one of the following

```
calculateTotalWheels (total2Wheels , 2)

calculateTotalWheels (total4Wheels , 4)

private calculateTotalWheels (def totalWheels, def numberOfWheels){
totalWheels+=numberOfWheels
}
```

However, I do not think that totalWheels+=totalWheels will work and will keep the value in the 2 global variables : total2Wheels and total4Wheels

Thanks,

Kat

Comment: Are the numbers decimals? How about making `total2Wheels` and `total4Wheels` `AtomicLong` objects and call increment methods on them from the method? If they're decimals, you could create a custom class that emulates similar behavior.

Comment: Most of the variables I pass are Decimals, but there are also some booleans, Shall I use AtomicBoolean for this case?

Comment: You could use an atomic boolean for that, although I'd personally avoid spreading the logic behind a single flag's value. Maybe a single class encapsulating the update logic is better, but it would not be worth it if all it did is duplicate `AtomicBoolean`.

Comment: Function that causes side effects (e.g. by modifying some global variables) is a bad design decision. Consider using pure function - a function that does not cause any side effects and is deterministic (it expects specific number of parameters and it returns a result based on these parameters in a deterministic manner). And if you want to test its efficiency in Groovy you can use GBench (https://github.com/gperfutils/gbench) tool for running benchmark tests.

Answer (score 0):

```
totals = [:]

def totalsAdd(int wheels){
    def key = "total${wheels}Wheels"
    totals[key] = (totals[key]?:0) + wheels
}

totalsAdd(2)
totalsAdd(4)
totalsAdd(2)
totalsAdd(2)
totalsAdd(4)

println totals
```

prints

```
[total2Wheels:6, total4Wheels:8]
```

finally you have a map and to get total 4 wheels: `totals.total4Wheels`